How to implent logic for deleting single task Todo app?
export function delTask(taskContainer) {
  const id = taskContainer.id
  const title = taskContainer.title
  let keyFound = false;
  const numItems = localStorage.length
  for (let i = numItems - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const key = localStorage.key(i)
    const value = localStorage.getItem(key)
    console.log("key" + key + " " + "id" + id)
    console.log(keyFound)
    if (keyFound) {
      let keyCount = key.substring(6 + title.length)
      keyCount = parseInt(keyCount) + 1
      if (key.startsWith("task_") && key.includes(title)) {
        const noCountKey = key.slice(0, -1)
        const newKey = noCountKey + keyCount
        localStorage.removeItem(key)
        localStorage.setItem(newKey, value)
        console.log(newKey)
      }
    }
    if (id.toString() === key.toString()) {
      keyFound = true
      console.log("keyis found" + keyFound)
      localStorage.removeItem(key)
    }
  }
}

Been stuck trying to debug this code I think there could be a logic flaw the idea is that local storage would contain something like this
project_project 1 2222-02-22dfwqfdqwd 
task_project 1_0 task 1
task_project 1_1 task 2
task_project 1_2 task 3
task_project 1_3 task 4

And the parameter contains the parent element of the delete button and it will go through each item in the local storage if it matches the parent element it will change key to true and delete that task, after that it goes through the other tasks with the same title and subtracts 1 from end of the key and makes a new one
If I delete the third task I get this in local storage
task_project 1_1 task 2
task_project 1_-1 task 1
task_project 1_NaN 2222-02-22dfwqfdqwd task_project 1_2 task 4

I am new to programming and am doing this for the Odin project any other approaches or a fix is greatly appreciated.

It looks like you're on the right track but I would recommend that you persist your data in JSON format and don't worry about updating keys because keys are rarely updated in the real world (unless that's a requirement for your project). You could store all your data as one list or object accessed by a single key, "tasks" for example. Parsing and manipulating JSON is far simpler and more readable than using individual keys in storage.

@BankBuilder yes that’s probably what I should have done and put all the data in a list, but now I would need to rewrite a lot of the logic, I found another solution with what I have, so thanks
